# jQuery age calculation is not calculating Leap Years

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

Iam Calculating Age by keeping today date and the selected date.

if i say **today (28th April 2016)** - Exact 3 years is displaying Correctly

if i say **yesterday (27th April 2016)** - **Still 3 years is displaying**, which should not be as 1 day is lesser for 3 years. I dont know where iam doing wrong in my code.

**[Age Calculator DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/nyp5waya/13/)**

Appreciate your Help!

Sample Code :

```
var getMonth, getDay, getYear, getDate, dob, today, age;
$(document).on('change', '#node_enfamama_registration_form_form_group_enr_hide_child_info .form-select', function() {
            $(this).each(function() {

               if ($(this).parents().hasClass('date-month')) {
                    getMonth = $(this).val();
                                        alert(getMonth)
                } 

                else if ($(this).parents().hasClass('date-day')) {
                    getDay = $(this).val();
                                        alert(getDay)
                }

                else if ($(this).parents().hasClass('date-year')) {
                    getYear = $(this).val();
                    alert(getYear)

                    getDate = getYear + "-" + getMonth + "-" + getDay;

                    alert("Month, day & year" + getDate)

                    $('.greater-msg').remove();
                    $('.less-then-msg').remove();               
                                        dob = new Date(getDate);
                    today = new Date();
                                        age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                        alert("Child Age is " + age)
                    //debugger;

                    /*
                    var birthDate = new Date(getDate);
                    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
                    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
                    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                        alert("aaa" + age)

                    age--;
                    }*/


                    if (age > 3) {
                        //debugger;
                        $(this).parents('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="greater-msg">You can also visit <a href="http://www.enfagrow4.com" target="_blank">www.enfagrow4.com</a> to know how you can keep giving your child the 360 advantage.</div>')
                    } else if (age <= -1) {
                        //$(this).parents('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="less-then-msg">Less Disclaimer: In compliance with EO51, Mead Johnson Nutrition cannot directly engage with mothers with children aged 0 to 3 years old. All content that you will receive via email will only be regarding your pregnancy. </div>')
                    } else if (age >= 0 && age <= 3) {
                        $(this).parents('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="less-then-msg">Less Disclaimer: In compliance with EO51, Mead Johnson Nutrition cannot directly engage with mothers with children aged 0 to 3 years old. All content that you will receive via email will only be regarding your pregnancy. </div>')
                    } else {
                    } 

                    function checkDate(){

                    }

                } else {}


            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you test? i have done the following: selecting 28-april-2013 => my child is 3. correct.  selecting 27-april-2013=>3 correct(since he is 3 and 1 day).  selecting 29-april-2013=>2  correct (one more day to 3).  i then set today in the javascript as yesterday(today=new Date('2016-04-27')) and selected 28-april-2013=>2 correct.

Comment: Use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to calculate the dates

Comment: @Laura :Thanks, correct,selecting 27-april-2013=>3 correct(since he is 3 and 1 day), then alert ("You can also visit") Message should display.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It's because you use age=Math.floor, which will be 3. not 3,something.   and then compare age >3

Comment: @Laura, so i should not use age=Math.floor, ?

Answer (score 1):

Math.floor() will always return an integer.
When you do age=Math.floor(...) that will be 3,not 3.005.
Use Math.floor() just when showing thevalue, but compare the real result in your if.
Try it like this:

```
    age = (today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    alert(age);
    alert("Child Age is " + Math.floor(age))
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working fine, but if i select Today's Date which is Equal to 3 then (Disclaimer ) Message has to come, Update fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/nyp5waya/1/

Comment: That's true, you have a problem for the exact day. You need to somehow know if the child becomes 3 that day. One way would be not to compare with 3, but use a more exact value. For example, a little test I made: if today, age=3.002..., if yesterday age=3.005... So you could round it somehow to 3 decimals and use that. But then again, I'm sure there's a smarter way, but can't figure it out right now :D

Comment: Thanks Again, will figure out a way :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the Issue,

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/nyp5waya/15/)

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.addChild = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            var getMonth, getDay, getYear, getDate, dob, today, age, contentParent;
            $('#node_enfamama_registration_form_form_group_enr_hide_child_info .form-select').change(function() {
                if ($(this).parents().hasClass('date-month')) {
                    getMonth = $(this).val();
                    contentParent = $(this).parents('.draggable');

                    if (getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null) {} else {
                        ageCalculation();
                    }

                } else if ($(this).parents().hasClass('date-day')) {
                    getDay = $(this).val();
                    contentParent = $(this).parents('.draggable');
                    if (getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null) {} else {
                        ageCalculation()
                    }

                } else if ($(this).parents().hasClass('date-year')) {
                    getYear = $(this).val();
                    contentParent = $(this).parents('.draggable');
                    if (getMonth == undefined || getMonth == "" || getMonth == null || getDay == undefined || getDay == "" || getDay == null || getYear == undefined || getYear == "" || getYear == null) {} else {
                        ageCalculation()
                    }

                } else {}
            });

            function ageCalculation() {
                getDate = getYear + "-" + getMonth + "-" + getDay;

                dob = new Date(getDate);
                today = new Date();
                age = (today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                if (age < 3 || age == 3 || age > 3 && age < 3.00452422294471007) {
                    $('.greater-msg, .less-then-msg').remove();
                    $(contentParent).find('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="less-then-msg">Disclaimer: In compliance with EO51,  cannot directly engage with mothers with children aged 0 to 3 years old. All content that you will receive via email will only be regarding your pregnancy. </div>')
                } else if (age > 3) {
                    $('.greater-msg, .less-then-msg').remove();
                    $(contentParent).find('.fieldset-wrapper').after('<div class="greater-msg">You can also visit <a href="http://www.enfagrow4.com">www.enfagrow4.com</a> to know how you can keep giving your child the 360 advantage.</div>')
                }
                if (age <= -1 || age <= -0 || age == 0 || age == -0) {
                    $('.greater-msg, .less-then-msg').remove();
                }
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```